# angular-ish function to output lorem ipsum text in a template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want some mechanism to input random placeholder text in my templates. For now I just thought filters would fit the bill. Hence I wrote something like this:

```
angular.module('web')
.filter('lorem', function(){
  var json = [
    //..data
  ];

  return function(_, ord) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    console.log('Index1:', index);
    if (index >= json.length) {
      index = json.length - 1;
    }
    console.log('Index2:', index);
    return json[index][ord];
  }
});
```

Here is an example of how its consumed in a template:

```
{{'' | lorem:'text1' }}
```

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/uL4AAYmmbWkC8ofQ00FO?p=preview

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. It is more dynamic. You can specify the number of text you need in `<li>`.

index.html

```
 <li ng-repeat="i in FinalJson">
    {{ i }}
  </li>
```

app.js

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.list = Array.apply(null, {length: 5}).map(Number.call, Number);
  console.log($scope.list);

   var json = [
    "ut commodo do",
    "ad amet reprehenderit officia pariatur deserunt magna",
    "pariatur culpa do",
    "do tempor laboris adipisicing est aliquip deserunt cillum occaecat culpa eu irure",
    "reprehenderit duis magna cillum veniam aute",
    "veniam nisi labore",
    "deserunt id nulla",
    "amet amet laborum laboris enim",
    "occaecat ullamco excepteur sit et",
    "laborum ut id"
  ];

  $scope.requiredText=5;
  var requiredText=5;
  var length = json.length;
  $scope.FinalJson=[];

  for(i=0;i<length;i++){
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
    if($scope.FinalJson.indexOf(json[index])==-1){
       $scope.FinalJson.push(json[index]);
    }
   if($scope.FinalJson.length==$scope.requiredText){
     break;
   }
 }
});
```

No need to make an extra filter for this. This should work great.

Comment: The filter approach is more global. Don't have to do something in the controller always.

Comment: What if you want 8 or 10 random sentences?